# regex expression help for string

Tags: regex

I have a string

```
2045111780&&-3&5&-7
```

I want a regex to give me groups as:

```
2045111780
&&-
3
```

... and then next groups as

```
3
&
5
```

... and so on.

I came up with `(\d+)(&&?-?)?` but that gives me groups as:

```
2045111780
&&-
```

... and then next groups as

```
3
&
```

... and so on.

**Note that I need the delim** ( regex: `&&?-?` )

Thanks.

update1: changed the groups output.

Comment: which language you using? PHP? C? ObjectiveC? Java?

Comment: You have to specify the language of the Regexes AND **It isn't clear how you would write a third group** 2045111780&&-3&5&-7&4&-8? Or it would repeat the double &&?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's not possible to share a match between groups (the -3 in your example). So, I recommend to do a 2 line processing: split the spring and take 2 pairs in an array. For example, using Perl:

```
$a = "2045111780&&-3&5&-7";
@pairs = split /&+/, $a;
# at this point you get $pairs[0] = '2045111780', $pairs[1] = '-3', ...
```

Comment: i agree. can't do it in regex itself.

Answer (score 0):

How about `(-?\d+|&+)`. It will match numbers with an optional minus and sequences of &s.

Comment: it does not group the delim. i want num1, delim, num2 as groups.

Comment: If you want to match the -3 twice, I think you'll have to write some code in addition to the regex.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to have overlapping matches.

You could use a regex like `(-?\d+)(&&?)(-?\d+)` and match it repeatedly until it fails, each time removing the beginning of the given string up to the start of the third group.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in perl like this:

```
$ perl -ne 'while (/(-?\d+)(&&?)(-?\d+)/g) { print $1, " ", $2, " ", $3, "\n"; pos() -= length($3); }'
2045111780&&-3&5&-7  # this is the input
2045111780 && -3
-3 & 5
5 & -7
```

But that's very ugly. The split approach by [Miguel Prz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779303/regex-expression-help-for-string/7779370#7779370) is much, much cleaner.